# automatically break in / before section / chapter

Tags: columnbreak

I have a problem with my latex code:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper,left=15mm,right=15mm, top=26mm, bottom=17mm} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[letterspace=30]{microtype} 
\linespread{1.13} 
\newlength{\sectionbaselineskip}
\setlength{\sectionbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{rotating}

\definecolor{SectionGray}{gray}{0.85}

\newenvironment{JustLeft}[1][\textwidth]
{\begin{minipage}[t]{#1}\begin{flushleft}}
{\end{flushleft}\end{minipage}}

\newenvironment{col}
{\raggedcolumns%
\begin{multicols}{2}%
\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}
{\end{multicols}}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textcolor{black!60}{\raisebox{0.5mm}{\rule{1.8mm}{1.8mm}}}}
\newcommand{\zitiert}[1]{\flqq{#1}\frqq}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{leftmargin=*}

% Chapter
% -------
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{12pt}{\sectionbaselineskip}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-10.5mm}} 
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{6.5mm}} 
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vskip11.5pt}

% Section
% -------
\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{10pt}{\sectionbaselineskip}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{8.5pt}{\sectionbaselineskip}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{8.5pt}{\sectionbaselineskip}\selectfont}
%\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{3ex}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3ex}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vskip11.5pt}

\newlength{\secboxlen}
\newlength{\sectextlen}
\newcounter{mylinecounter}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\newcommand{\SectionKopf}{\rule{0pt}{2.4ex}}
\newcommand{\SectionFuss}{\rule[-1.1ex]{0pt}{1ex}}

\newcommand{\TheSection}[3][n]{%
%           ===========
\setlength{\secboxlen}{\linewidth}%
\addtolength{\secboxlen}{-2\fboxsep}%
\setlength{\sectextlen}{\linewidth}%
\addtolength{\sectextlen}{-1cm}%
\stepcounter{section}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
\colorbox{SectionGray}{%
\begin{JustLeft}[\secboxlen]%
\fontsize{10pt}{\sectionbaselineskip}\selectfont%
\makebox[1mm]{}\bfseries\makebox[9mm][l]{\thesection}%
\begin{JustLeft}[\sectextlen]%
{\SectionKopf#3\SectionFuss}%
\end{JustLeft}%
\end{JustLeft}}%
}%
}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}
{% IF
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bfseries\numberline{\thesection}#3}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\mdseries}}%
}%
{% ELSE
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection}#3}%
}%
\par%
\setcounter{mylinecounter}{1}%
\whiledo{\value{mylinecounter}<#2}{\nothing\\\stepcounter{mylinecounter}}%
}


\newcommand{\chapterend}{%
%           ========
\\[2\baselineskip]%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{2018 FIFA World Cup}

\begin{col}
\TheSection{1}{Budget}
At an estimated cost of over 14.2 billion as of June 2018, it is the most expensive World Cup in history, surpassing the cost of the 2014 FIFA World Cup in Brazil.

The Russian government had originally earmarked a budget of around 20 billion which was later slashed to 10 billion for the preparations of the World Cup, of which half is spent on transport infrastructure. As part of the program for preparation to the 2018 FIFA World Cup, a federal sub-program "Construction and Renovation of Transport Infrastructure" was implemented with a total budget of 352.5 billion rubles, with 170.3 billion coming from the federal budget, 35.1 billion from regional budgets, and 147.1 billion from investors. The biggest item of federal spending was the aviation infrastructure (117.8 billion rubles). Construction of new hotels was a crucial area of infrastructure development in the World Cup host cities. Costs continued to balloon as preparations were underway.\chapterend
%
\TheSection{1}{Infrastructure spending}
Platov International Airport in Rostov-on-Don was upgraded with automated air traffic control systems, modern surveillance, navigation, communication, control, and meteorological support systems. Koltsovo Airport in Yekaterinburg was upgraded with radio-engineering tools for flight operation and received its second runway strip. Saransk Airport received a new navigation system; the city also got two new hotels, Mercure Saransk Centre (Accor Hotels) and Four Points by Sheraton Saransk (Starwood Hotels) as well as few other smaller accommodation facilities. In Samara, new tram lines were laid.] Khrabrovo Airport in Kaliningrad was upgraded with radio navigation and weather equipment.Renovation and upgrade of radio-engineering tools for flight operation was completed in the airports of Moscow, Saint Petersburg, Volgograd, Samara, Yekaterinburg, Kazan and Sochi. On 27 March, the Ministry of Construction Industry, Housing and Utilities Sector of Russia reported that all communications within its area of responsibility have been commissioned. The last facility commissioned was a waste treatment station in Volgograd. In Yekaterinburg, where four matches are hosted, hosting costs increased to over 7.4 billion rubles, over-running the 5.6 billion rubles originally allocated from the state and regional budget.\chapterend
%
\TheSection{1}{Volunteers}
Volunteer applications to the Russia 2018 Local Organising Committee opened on 1 June 2016. The 2018 FIFA World Cup Russia Volunteer Program received about 177,000 applications, and engaged a total of 35,000 volunteers. They received training at 15 Volunteer Centres of the Local Organising Committee based in 15 universities, and in Volunteer Centres in the host cities. Preference, especially in the key areas, was given to those with knowledge of foreign languages and volunteering experience, but not necessarily to Russian nationals.\chapterend
%
\TheSection{1}{Transport}
Free public transport services were offered for ticketholders during the World Cup.
\chapterend
%
\TheSection{1}{Schedule}
The full schedule was announced by FIFA on 24 July 2015 (without kick-off times, which were confirmed later). On 1 December 2017, following the final draw, six kick-off times were adjusted by FIFA.
Russia was placed in position A1 in the group stage and played in the opening match at the Luzhniki Stadium in Moscow on 14 June against Saudi Arabia, the two lowest ranked teams of the tournament at the time of the final draw.The Luzhniki Stadium also hosted the second semi-final on 11 July and the final on 15 July. The Krestovsky Stadium in Saint Petersburg hosted the first semi-final on 10 July and the third place play-off on 14 July.

\newpage
\end{col}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the MWE is not really minimal:( I hope somebody can help me anyway.
Using this code I get something like
[image]

I would like to do the columnbreak before the section "0.5 Shedule" automatically (without `\columnbreak` in the document). I guess there is a way to solve this problem using some code in de preamble, but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: For future questions where you need text to fill space, you can use the lipsum or blindtext packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the style of your code (the layout may be fine, but the TeX code you are using...). Anyway, you can just add `\nopagebreak` at the end of your `\TheSection` macro:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=8.5pt,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper,left=15mm,right=15mm, top=26mm, bottom=17mm} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[letterspace=30]{microtype} 
\linespread{1.13} 
\newlength{\sectionbaselineskip}
\setlength{\sectionbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{rotating}

\definecolor{SectionGray}{gray}{0.85}

\newenvironment{JustLeft}[1][\textwidth]
{\begin{minipage}[t]{#1}\begin{flushleft}}
{\end{flushleft}\end{minipage}}

\newenvironment{col}
{\raggedcolumns%
\begin{multicols}{2}%
\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}
{\end{multicols}}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textcolor{black!60}{\raisebox{0.5mm}{\rule{1.8mm}{1.8mm}}}}
\newcommand{\zitiert}[1]{\flqq{#1}\frqq}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{leftmargin=*}

% Chapter
% -------
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\fontsize{12pt}{\sectionbaselineskip}\selectfont}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-10.5mm}} 
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{6.5mm}} 
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vskip11.5pt}

% Section
% -------
\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{10pt}{\sectionbaselineskip}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{8.5pt}{\sectionbaselineskip}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{8.5pt}{\sectionbaselineskip}\selectfont}
%\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{3ex}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3ex}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vskip11.5pt}

\newlength{\secboxlen}
\newlength{\sectextlen}
\newcounter{mylinecounter}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\newcommand{\SectionKopf}{\rule{0pt}{2.4ex}}
\newcommand{\SectionFuss}{\rule[-1.1ex]{0pt}{1ex}}

\newcommand{\TheSection}[3][n]{%
%           ===========
\setlength{\secboxlen}{\linewidth}%
\addtolength{\secboxlen}{-2\fboxsep}%
\setlength{\sectextlen}{\linewidth}%
\addtolength{\sectextlen}{-1cm}%
\stepcounter{section}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
\colorbox{SectionGray}{%
\begin{JustLeft}[\secboxlen]%
\fontsize{10pt}{\sectionbaselineskip}\selectfont%
\makebox[1mm]{}\bfseries\makebox[9mm][l]{\thesection}%
\begin{JustLeft}[\sectextlen]%
{\SectionKopf#3\SectionFuss}%
\end{JustLeft}%
\end{JustLeft}}%
}%
}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}
{% IF
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\bfseries\numberline{\thesection}#3}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\mdseries}}%
}%
{% ELSE
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{\thesection}#3}%
}%
\par%
\setcounter{mylinecounter}{1}%
\whiledo{\value{mylinecounter}<#2}{\nothing\\\stepcounter{mylinecounter}}%
\nopagebreak%
}


\newcommand{\chapterend}{%
%           ========
\\[2\baselineskip]%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{2018 FIFA World Cup}

\begin{col}
\TheSection{1}{Budget}
At an estimated cost of over 14.2 billion as of June 2018, it is the most expensive World Cup in history, surpassing the cost of the 2014 FIFA World Cup in Brazil.

The Russian government had originally earmarked a budget of around 20 billion which was later slashed to 10 billion for the preparations of the World Cup, of which half is spent on transport infrastructure. As part of the program for preparation to the 2018 FIFA World Cup, a federal sub-program "Construction and Renovation of Transport Infrastructure" was implemented with a total budget of 352.5 billion rubles, with 170.3 billion coming from the federal budget, 35.1 billion from regional budgets, and 147.1 billion from investors. The biggest item of federal spending was the aviation infrastructure (117.8 billion rubles). Construction of new hotels was a crucial area of infrastructure development in the World Cup host cities. Costs continued to balloon as preparations were underway.\chapterend
%
\TheSection{1}{Infrastructure spending}
Platov International Airport in Rostov-on-Don was upgraded with automated air traffic control systems, modern surveillance, navigation, communication, control, and meteorological support systems. Koltsovo Airport in Yekaterinburg was upgraded with radio-engineering tools for flight operation and received its second runway strip. Saransk Airport received a new navigation system; the city also got two new hotels, Mercure Saransk Centre (Accor Hotels) and Four Points by Sheraton Saransk (Starwood Hotels) as well as few other smaller accommodation facilities. In Samara, new tram lines were laid.] Khrabrovo Airport in Kaliningrad was upgraded with radio navigation and weather equipment.Renovation and upgrade of radio-engineering tools for flight operation was completed in the airports of Moscow, Saint Petersburg, Volgograd, Samara, Yekaterinburg, Kazan and Sochi. On 27 March, the Ministry of Construction Industry, Housing and Utilities Sector of Russia reported that all communications within its area of responsibility have been commissioned. The last facility commissioned was a waste treatment station in Volgograd. In Yekaterinburg, where four matches are hosted, hosting costs increased to over 7.4 billion rubles, over-running the 5.6 billion rubles originally allocated from the state and regional budget.\chapterend
%
\TheSection{1}{Volunteers}
Volunteer applications to the Russia 2018 Local Organising Committee opened on 1 June 2016. The 2018 FIFA World Cup Russia Volunteer Program received about 177,000 applications, and engaged a total of 35,000 volunteers. They received training at 15 Volunteer Centres of the Local Organising Committee based in 15 universities, and in Volunteer Centres in the host cities. Preference, especially in the key areas, was given to those with knowledge of foreign languages and volunteering experience, but not necessarily to Russian nationals.\chapterend
%
\TheSection{1}{Transport}
Free public transport services were offered for ticketholders during the World Cup.
\chapterend
%
\TheSection{1}{Schedule}
The full schedule was announced by FIFA on 24 July 2015 (without kick-off times, which were confirmed later). On 1 December 2017, following the final draw, six kick-off times were adjusted by FIFA.
Russia was placed in position A1 in the group stage and played in the opening match at the Luzhniki Stadium in Moscow on 14 June against Saudi Arabia, the two lowest ranked teams of the tournament at the time of the final draw.The Luzhniki Stadium also hosted the second semi-final on 11 July and the final on 15 July. The Krestovsky Stadium in Saint Petersburg hosted the first semi-final on 10 July and the third place play-off on 14 July.

\newpage
\end{col}
\end{document}
```

[image]